# Time a function and get the returned value

Tags: python, performance, time

I know I can use this

```
from timeit import timeit
test = lambda f: timeit(lambda:f(100), number=1)
t1 = test(hello)
```

To time how long it takes the `hello` function to run with argument `100`. But let's say my `hello` function returns the string `'world'` and I want to store that returned value *and* also have to the time it took to execute.

Can that be done?

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve here? If you're setting `number=1`, `timeit` probably isn't the right tool for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to time how long it takes to run `hello(100)` once. This method was the top answer on the post I got it from. Could you suggest which other method you would use please? I don't understand the down vote...

Comment: And what will you be doing with the return value? If you just want to ensure it's what you expect, consider `assert`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe For my lab my lecturer is asking that we time all our functions during the actual run. This is not just to check performance. I need to time my function AND use it's results as arguments for later functions in the program.

Comment: You likely want something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script - Voting to close your question as a duplicate

Comment: Have you tried to write a function that returns a tuple or array so that you get a return of `(functionResult, timeResult)` ?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to time specific calls to specific functions, you can do the following. This will get you the exact time of one run. However, you probably just want to use timeit or profile to get a more exact picture of what your program is doing. Those tools aggregate multiple runs to get a more accurate average case result.

Make a function that takes a function to call, records the time, then runs the function and returns the value and time delta.

```
import time

def timed(func, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    out = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return out, time.time() - start

def my_func(value):
    time.sleep(value)
    return value

print(timed(my_func(5)))  # (5, 5.0050437450408936)
```